# printing subsets of an array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to print subsets of an array in python but i am get None type is not iterable error

```
def printSubs(l,out):
  if (len(l) == 0):
    print(*out)
    return

  printSubs(l[1:],out)
  printSubs(l[1:],out.append(l[0]))
printSubs([15,20,12],[])
```

this throws None type is not iterable error but when i copy the out into a new array and then append l[0] to it and pass it to the second function call it works fine

```
def printSubs(l,out):
  if (len(l) == 0):
    print(*out)
    return

  printSubs(l[1:],out)
  newOut = [i for i in out]
  newOut.append(l[0])

  printSubs(l[1:],newOut)
printSubs([15,20,12],[])
```

this code works fine can anyone explain me why is it happening to me it seems both code does the same thing as the out array is having different states in diffrent function calls. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: printSubs(l[1:],out.append(l[0])) is never getting hit, coz the recursive stack of the previous statement hits the if statement, without appending anything to the out array and the out array is still empty.

Comment: @3xt can u plz elaborate a bit on this thanks

Answer (score 1):

`out.append(l[0])` doesn't return anything and that's what you're passing in function. That's why this error.

Instead of -

```
  printSubs(l[1:],out)
  printSubs(l[1:],out.append(l[0]))
```

You have to do -

```
  printSubs(l[1:],out)
  out.append(l[0])
  printSubs(l[1:],out)
```

Comment: why does out.append(l[0]) has to return anything what essentially we are doing is trying to append l[0] to whatever the previous state of out array was.Btw tried the approach u suggested the error prevails

12
12 20
12 20 12
12 20 12 15
12 20 12 15 12
12 20 12 15 12 20
12 20 12 15 12 20 12 gives wrong output

Comment: While calling a function with `printSubs(l[1:],out.append(l[0]))`, in second parameter you're trying to pass the value that will be returned after `.append()` method. And since it simply appends the value and returns **nothing**, you're getting **NoneType**. I hope you're getting what I am trying to say. If not, you gotta see how append in list works.